# Using datetime pickers in mysql in select statment

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two date time pickers where I select the range from those datetime pickers to retrieve information from table but I get error as it calculates all the images and gives me the count on single date and not datewise.

```
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(String.Format(
      "SELECT   datetime ," +
      "sum(CASE action when '2' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedIMG, " +
      "sum(CASE action when '3' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedIMG, " +
      "sum(CASE action when '4' then 1 else 0 end) as ChangeIMG " +
      "FROM customer_1.audit_trail " +
      //"GROUP BY (dateonly)" +
     // "ORDER BY  (dateonly) asc  " +
      "where datetime BETWEEN '{0}' and '{1}'",
      start.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), 
      end.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
      "GROUP BY (datetime)" ), conn);
                sda.Fill(db);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = db;
```

Comment: Could you add the error you're getting to your question?

Comment: I get the output as  01/03/2013 00:09 466269 123249 480542 but need to get the output  from datetime picker1 date to datetime picker 2 date .. i.e datewise.

Comment: To accomplish that you'd need to remove the GROUP BY statement as well as the SUM()

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use datetime in mysql and c# where date range in between.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949229/how-to-use-datetime-in-mysql-and-c-sharp-where-date-range-in-between)

Comment: This is the same exact question as [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17949229/62576) that was posted an hour earlier.

Comment: Hi Dhaulagiri i tried to remove the group by and sum it display the reuslts as 1 and 0 but I need the output as the sum of accepted images on that particular day ,week and month can you please tell me how to do that..i am trying it differnet ways but unsucccessfull.

Comment: can anyone help me with this...